# Как создать ситуация выпадения исключения OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, память, стек, outofmemoryerror, heap

Как создать ситуация выпадения исключения OutOfMemoryError?

Ответ с примером кода, пожалуйста

Comment: Можно так `throw new OutOfMemoryError()`

Comment: Если нужно реально сожрать память, то можно рекурсию, на каждом шаге делать `new byte[]` с 1 гигом памяти + GC.KeepAlive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (true) {
            Main a = new Main();
            sb.append(a.toString());
        }
    }
}
```